# Help!!! DSolve is coming out weirdly

Tags: differential-equations

The equation I am entering is 2′′ +′ +=4ln() and it looks like

```
DSolve[x^2 y''[x] + xy'[x] + y[x] == Exp[4 Log (x)], y[x], x]
```

, it comes out as

```
{{y[x] -> Sqrt[x] C[1] Cos[1/2 Sqrt[3] Log[x]] + 
Sqrt[x] C[2] Sin[1/2 Sqrt[3] Log[x]] + 
Sqrt[x] Cos[
  1/2 Sqrt[3] Log[x]] Inactive[Integrate][-((
   2 Sin[1/2 Sqrt[3] Log[K[1]]] (E^(4 Log K[1]) - 
      Derivative[1][xy][K[1]]))/(Sqrt[3] K[1]^(3/2))), {K[1], 1, 
   x}] + Sqrt[x]
  Sin[1/2 Sqrt[3] Log[x]] Inactive[Integrate][(
  2 Cos[1/2 Sqrt[3] Log[K[2]]] (E^(4 Log K[2]) - 
     Derivative[1][xy][K[2]]))/(
  Sqrt[3] K[2]^(3/2)), {K[2], 1, x}]}}
```

I apologize for how it looks, but I do not how what I am doing wrong.  I feel like I have tried everything to fix it, but nothing works.  If someone could tell me what to do it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You probably need a space between `x` and `y'` in the term `xy'[x]`

Comment: Also change parentheses after `Log` to `[ ]` : ```DSolve[x^2 y''[x] + x y'[x] + y[x] == Exp[4 Log [x]], y[x], x]```

Comment: Thank you!  Those both seemed to help.  I'll definitely try to keep those two things in mind in the futre.