# Available Methods for DSolve?

Tags: differential-equations, symbolic, undocumented

I would like to know, apart from `Method->Automatic` what are available methods for `DSolve`.

```
sol = DSolve[equationList, f[t], t, Method -> "Holonomic"]
```

I discovered only "Holonomic". Are there more available methods and if yes for what kind of problems are they good for? I failed to find anything in the documentation.

Comment: `"EvaluateIntegrals" | "InactiveIntegrals" | "Holonomic" | Automatic` are the ones I know....

Comment: For instance, `DSolve[x^2 y''[x] + xy'[x] + y[x] == Exp[4 Log [x]], y[x], x, Method -> "EvaluateIntegrals"]` takes 400+ sec. and produces the same answer as `DSolve[x^2 y''[x] + xy'[x] + y[x] == Exp[4 Log [x]], y[x], x]` in around 0.35 sec.  `"InactiveIntegrals"` seems the same as `Automatic`, and **allows** `Inactive[]` integrals, but does not force them. (Example from https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/258268/help-dsolve-is-coming-out-weirdly)

Comment: Found another: `eqns = {y'[t] == z[t], z'[t] == -10, y[0] == 1, z[0] == 0};
events = {WhenEvent[y[t] == 0, {y[t] -> 0, z[t] -> -(70/100) z[t]}]};
sol = DSolve[Join[eqns, events], {y[t], z[t]}, {t, 0, 2}, 
  Method -> {"Events", "MaxEvents" -> 3}]`

Answer (score 6):

#### Summary

These are what I've discovered (in V13.1):

```
Method -> Automatic
Method -> "EvaluateIntegrals"
Method -> "InactiveIntegrals" (* same as Automatic? *)
Method -> {"Events", "MaxEvents" -> n}
Method -> "Holonomic"
```

I don't believe they can be mixed. If you do, what happens varies. Either `DSolve` returns unevaluated or the combination is treated as `Automatic`. For instance, `Method -> {"EvaluateIntegrals", {"Events", "MaxEvents" -> 3}}` is treated as `Automatic` in `"Events"` example and leads to unevaluated `DSolve[]` in the other examples below. Method parsing does not seem to be as robust as in `NDSolve` or `NIntegrate` (probably why `IncludeSingularSolutions` is a separate option and not a `Method` option).

#### `Method -> "EvaluateIntegrals"`

The following takes 400+ sec. and produces the same answer as
`Method -> Automatic`, with unevaluated integrals, in this case:

```
DSolve[x^2 y''[x] + xy'[x] + y[x] == Exp[4 Log [x]], y[x], x,
 Method -> "EvaluateIntegrals"]
```

#### `Method -> "InactiveIntegrals"`

`Method -> "InactiveIntegrals"` seems the same as `Method -> Automatic`, and **allows** `Inactive[]` integrals, but does not force them. The following takes around 0.35 sec. with either option setting and produces the same result

```
DSolve[x^2 y''[x] + xy'[x] + y[x] == Exp[4 Log [x]], y[x], x,
 Method -> "InactiveIntegrals"]
```

The foregoing examples are adapted from [Help!!! DSolve is coming out weirdly](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/258268)

#### `Method -> {"Events", "MaxEvents" -> 3}`

The following is adapted from the docs for `DSolve` and without the `"MaxEvents"` constraint produces a `Piecewise` solution with five cases.

```
eqns = {y'[t] == z[t], z'[t] == -10, y[0] == 1, z[0] == 0};
events = {WhenEvent[y[t] == 0,
 {y[t] -> 0, z[t] -> -(70/100) z[t]}]};
sol = DSolve[Join[eqns, events], {y[t], z[t]}, {t, 0, 2},
 Method -> {"Events", "MaxEvents" -> 3}]
```

> DSolve::maxev: The maximum number of events has been reached. The currently computed solution has been returned.
>
> ```
> (* output: Piecewise with three cases *)
> ```

#### `Method -> "Holonomic"`

For linear equations, it produces a `DifferentialRoot`:

```
DSolve[y'[x] == y[x], y, x, Method -> "Holonomic"]
(*
{{y -> DifferentialRoot[
 Function[{\[FormalY], \[FormalX]},
  {-\[FormalY][\[FormalX]] + \[FormalY]'[\[FormalX]] == 0,
  \[FormalY][0] == C[1]}]]}}
*)
```

Unceremoniously fails on nonlinear equations:

```
DSolve[y'[x] == y[x]^2, y, x, Method -> "Holonomic"]
(*
DSolve[Derivative[1][y][x] == y[x]^2, y, x, Method -> "Holonomic"]
*)
```